# Cast MyClass<string> to MyClass<object> fails in runtime

Tags: c#, generics

In developing a class that should handle various generic lambda expressions, I fell into a rather familiar hole: I had a `MyClass<T>` class, and I tried to cast `MyClass<string>` to `MyClass<object>`, like so:

```
MyClass<string> myClassString = GetMyClass(); // Returns MyClass<String>
MyClass<object> myClassObject = myClassString;
```

Doing so returned an compilation error saying there there's no implicit conversion between the two types, but that an explicit conversion does exist. So I added the explicit conversion:

```
MyClass<object> myClassObject = (MyClass<object>)myClassString;
```

Now the code compiled, but failed in runtime, claiming the conversion is illegal.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and the code is part of a Portable Class Library project compiled with C# 5.

Just to make sure, I replaced `MyClass` `IList` - the same behavior appeared - an explicit conversion is allowed, but fails during run-time.

Why? Why does the compiler accept this? What's the point of the explicit conversion if it fails in runtime?

Comment: I can't get your code to compile, even with the explicit cast. Is `MyClass<T>` actually an interface or a delegate?

Comment: @svick is right. If it's a class, there's no way a `MyClass<string>` could inherit from a `MyClass<object>` because a class can have only one direct base class, so the inheritance chain of classes is just a "line", and `MyClass<string>` can't have `MyClass<object>` in its inheritance line. With interfaces, even interfaces not covariant in their type argument, it's different. Therefore, with classes, no "explicit conversion exists", except if you have first upcasted to `object` or some other base class. In the latter case it has to fail runtime, of course.

Comment: What's the base class of `MyClass<T>`, and what's the _declared_ return type of the method `GetMyClass()`?

Comment: These guys are right; either you are mistaken or there is some detail you've left out. The compiler should not allow an impossible conversion in a cast.

Answer (score 5):

In order to allow the cast, you need to mark it as covariant. However, covariance is only allowed for interfaces (and delegates). This would look like:

```
interface MyInterface<out T> ...
```

The reason why you can compile the explicit cast is probably that the compiler assumes that the return value of `GetMyClass()` could be a `MyClass<object>`. But That's hard to say without the declaration.

Comment: MyClass<T> implements IMyClass<T> for that reason exactly. I'll add the 'out' and see. I've edited the question to show what GetMyClass() returns - its a MyClass<string> .

Answer (score 3):

To be able to cast `MyClass<string>` to `MyClass<object>` you need to fulfill the following:

- `MyClass<T>` must be an interface, e.g. `IMyClass<T>`.
- You need to add the `out` keyword to the type parameter `T`, making the type parameter *covariant*.
- The type parameter `T` may only appear in output positions of the members of the interface.

For example:

```
public interface IMyClass<out T>
{
    T GetItem();    // T in an output position
}
```

Now you can cast it:

```
IMyClass<string> myClassString;
IMyClass<object> myClassObject = (IMyClass<object>)myClassString;
```

Comment: Technically, it could also be a delegate, but that's probably not applicable here.

Comment: Indeed, but without the `out T` part of the declaration, the compiler still allows the cast and the runtime rejects it. Why?

Comment: @zmbq Because you could have a class that implements both versions of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you have classes A and B and you want to cast B to A then one of the following must be true:

- B derives/implements A or vice versa
- There is an explicit cast operator defined from B to A

None of the above is true in your case so the cast is invalid.

If your class implements IEnumerable you may use an extension method

```
using System.Linq
...
MyClass<Object> asObject = GetMyClass().Cast<Object>();
```

Otherwise, write an explicit operator or function that does the conversion:

```
public MyClass<Base> ConvertToBase<Base, Derived>(MyClass<Derived>) where Derived : Base
{
    // construct and return the appropriate object
}
```

Comment: `System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast()` certainly won't work here, that wors only on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: My bad, whenever I see a generic, I immediately think it is an IEnumerable<T>. Check out the edited answer.

Comment: Even if `MyClass` implemented `IEnumerable`, that code still wouldn't work, you would need `IEnumerable<Object> asObject = GetMyClass().Cast<Object>();`. And there is at least one more case when you can cast: when A derives from B (you can cast to base class).

Comment: The cast is acceptable by the compiler, but fails at runtime. I wouldn't be asking if I got a compilation error.

Answer (score -2):

use Conversion operator to implement casting of your class to another classes

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Could you explain how exactly would you use that to cast `MyClass<string>` to `MyClass<object>`? Because I think you can't use the conversion operator for that.